# What is "~" in regex?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tilde operator in Regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938100/tilde-operator-in-regular-expressions)

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
```

The code is from http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

I searched for what "~" is in regex and did not find an answer.

What does it do?

Comment: It appears to be using `~` as a delimiter instead of `/` which is most commonly used.

Comment: Well, I looked into some refs/tuts regarding regex too and did not find any. Then I searched for "~" while I did't know how the symbol is called exactly. I guess there are a lot of people performing this kind of search..

Comment: I believe you still get the rep if the question is closed, so no worries.

Comment: Of course, no problem.. I was just saying.

Comment: The other question doesn't have the symbol `~` in its question text. I don't know if SO's search engine searches symbols as keywords but if so, then this question could still be helpful.

Comment: Yup, I mentioned that people might seach for that and while on page the first big H1 contains the symbol, it is a SEO way to get people faster to the answer..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first and last character of a regular expression in PHP (and other implementations) is known as the *delimiter*. Normally, you see a `/` being used, but in this case, someone chose `~`. [Read more here.](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Not sure why `~` was chosen though; probably a habit of that particular developer. Normally, one chooses a different delimiter over `/` when the regular expression itself will contain slashes (*e.g.* matching URLs), so that slashes don't need to be escaped every time.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol `~` is just used as delimiter in PHP regexps.