# meaning of the letter "~" in regex

Tags: php, regex

what is the meaning of the "~" in regex .For example in this code

```
preg_match("~^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$~",$value)
```

this code check for wether the phone number contains extension or not. I have tried to remove to the "~" in this code and got an error like this:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\my_application\Phone.php on line 21

Comment: It is regex bound markers. In most regexes `/` are used instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938100/tilde-operator-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This character is called **[Tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)** and in this case is simply a placeholder, it's just being used as a delimiter. It is simply delimiting the start and end of your regex pattern.